# Escape chars for SQLite3 command (without prepare)

Tags: sqlite, escaping

I am creating a C++ program which will output a series of SQL statements (create, insert, etc) and write them to a file.  This file will be used to create and populate a SQLite3 database.

I need to ensure that and values inserted are properly escaped so they can fit within the double quoted string (in the insert statement).  Since there is no SQLite database available (this program just writes to a text file), I cannot use prepare.  Can someone tell me which characters need to be escaped and how?

So far I've only found that the ' character needs to be escaped with another '

Comment: `'` is the only symbol according ansi sql which should be escaped as `''`, all other symbols, like `"` or `\\` are rdbms specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a string, the only character to be escaped is the quote `'` itself.

As for table/column names, you need to [quote them](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) if they conflict with SQL keywords.